# Как вывести имя директории в bat файле?

Tags: bat

Из контекстного меню проводника на папке запускаю команду *\2.bat "%1"
в bat файле:
echo %~dp1
получаю:
C:\Users/*\Desktop\Петли\ 
как я могу получить название директории в bat файле?
Команда %~n1 не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Помогла данная команда:
for %%i in (%1) do set "folder_name=%%~nxi"

Answer (score 0):

```
echo %cd%
```

Это Вы имели ввиду?
Оно выводит текущую директорию (не батника и не конкретно название директории)